# Factory Girl: create vs build, different behavior needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

What I need is a way inside a Factory.define block to know if the factory has been called using create or build, either explicitly or simply using the default strategy.

I have a factory that has to manually adjust associations that the original author of the code took so far off the rails that normal creation barfs and normal build can be managed. I don't want to adjust those associations in the build case, but I have to in the create case.

I've been looking to see if there is something analogous to 'current_strategy' but I haven't seen anything yet. I know I can distinguish using after_create vs. after_build, but the original author made it so that the act of saving the object without doing the adjustments causes massive unhappiness--save exceptions and garbage in the database.

I currently have no mandate to fix the "models" he wrote and the existing rspec tests use the differentiation to do the right thing at any time. In every case the prior test author(s) have opted to simply never use create, which means setting up most of the test data is an arcane and lengthy process.

Any help would be deeply appreciated--I'm still exercising my GoogleFu but would love to be short circuited...

Oh, this is in Rails 2 (/cry)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a very strange problem indeed, but since you say that you're cleaning up someone else's code, I'll assume there's no easy way out of this.

I wouldn't approach this from the factory side. The factory shouldn't care because the model (**not the factory**) is supposed to be the gatekeeper of validity in terms of object structure and associations.

I would write specs that separately `create` and `build` objects, and test their associations to make sure they are correct (according to what you want the **new behavior** to ultimately be). Then, get those specs to pass by refactoring the **models** to do what you actually need them to do. This is how you clean up legacy code, and alter its behavior - write tests that will pass when the new functionality is correct, and refactor until they pass, making incremental changes with each test/refactoring.

When your new specs are passing, you're well on your way. If the previous author put in specs of their own that verify the previous behavior, then you'll have to work on figuring out which, if any, of those tests are currently valid (many of them may be, since they represent the requirements that the app currently fulfils), and removing ones that aren't.

Comment: definitely the best approach. My challenge is that the models are organized in such a way that while they have associations, create and new on a specific, central handful of them simply don't work. you have to call this thing create_standard and new_standard which builds everything up and glues it together. Additionally despite his associations he links models together by manually setting the ids of each of a few related objects to be the same value. He's got a homegrown plugin he wrote to allow him to set ids. He's done so much evil...

Comment: And this was all originally written in Rails, or was it converted from another code base (that's me trying to make something crazy make sense)? Sounds like a nightmare. Hope it wasn't an explicit attempt at obfuscation (which really benefits no one in the long run).

Comment: Is there any hope of getting to the *reasons why* it was implemented this way, in order to restructure it in a more useful fashion? Are you starting somewhat from scratch, or is this a code base whose overall design decisions you are familiar with?

Comment: It's fairly large, the guy who originally designed it and implemented it only seems to half understand Rails and what he didn't understand he just made up his own solutions. I really really wish we could just rip it apart but my initial task is just to get the rspec tests to a place where they are a useful feedback tool :P And yeah, it's a nightmare, but I could be working in Java and that would be worse!